# How to make a custom added datagrid child scrolls with its parent?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid

I'd like to know if it is possible to make a custom datagrid child scrolls with its parent.

I've added to my mx DataGrid some custom components as its childs. But when I scroll my DataGrid Vertically or Horizontaly, my added children do not move with the DataGrid cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple to solve, I just needed to put my component in a mx:Canvas e set its scrollBarPosition the same as myDataGrid scrollBarPosition. ;)